# How to perform url requests one-by-one and not to cause stack overflow? (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stack-overflow

Currently i have this code

```
function DownloadPage(uri) {
    request(uri, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            nextURL = FindURLBySomeLogic(body);
            DownloadPage(nextURL);
        }
    });
}
DownloadPage("http://example.com/");
```

but i think that i will get stack overflow after some amount of pages. Amount of pages are infinite. How can I avoid this? Every page contain only JSON data.

Comment: It is already one by one, since you download one after the previous is done.

Comment: Well, if you truly have an infinite amount of pages then we have a lot to consider, such as your storage medium.

Comment: @mccainz there is no problem with storage. By "infinite amount of pages" i mean that pages will appear with time. This requests will always work in background without stopping.

Comment: `console.log(new Error().stack);` in `DownloadPage` will show you that the stack size does not increase.

Comment: @user3173842 you are actually right. Do you want to answer on this question or i can do it by myself? I'm asking this because you will get some rating.

Comment: @user3239600: thanks, just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(new Error().stack);` in `DownloadPage` will show you that the stack size does not increase because `request` is async.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to synchronize your asynchronous requests. As long as you don't call async.js callbacks in single tick, it should be fine for any length of array. Since all your requests are requesting a page, it will be asynchronous and shouldn't create any problem. Take a look at the async.js page, it provides a lot of functions to synchronize your requests. If you don't necessarily need one-by-one request, then you can just go for setTimeout based requests and set the timeout duration based on the network speed so that your requests follow an approximate one-by-one request.